# Рейтинг игроков на Google Play

Tags: java, android, google-play

Вобщем, есть игра типа "Викторина" и естественно нужно было подключить рейтинг, подключил рейтинг `Google Play`, так вот незадача в том, что рейтинг в `Google Play`, можно только увеличивать, а уменьшать нельзя. Как мне при типе игры "Викторина", выбрать лучшего игрока?

---

Я думал сделать так, если человек отвечает правильно +1 балл, если нет, то -1 балл, а при таком раскладе, что рейтинг `Google Play` уменьшать нельзя, только прибавлять, как мне выявить лучшего? 
Просто если прибавлять в рейтинг только за правильные ответы, то, это не будет честным рейтингом, на первом месте будет тот, у кого просто будет больше правильных ответов, не учитывая неправильные, хоть даже у него будут неправильных ответов больше, чем правильных, то он все равно будет на первом, как решить это в `Google Play`? Или нужно свой рейтинг делать на сервере?

Answer (score 0):

Правильный ответ - 1 балл. Неправильный ответ 0. Зачем уменьшать за неправильный ответ?

Вы может сделать следующий вариант - рейтинг зависит от рейтинга игроков давших ответ. Например, если игрок с высоким рейтингом дал правильный ответ, то ему добавляется меньше рейтинга, чем игроку с маленьким рейтингом за тот же ответ. То есть если игрок просто старается угадывать, то ему рейтинг не увеличивается, а у остальных он растет.

Comment: так это будет неправильным рейтингом, как написал выше, на первом месте будет тот, кто больше всего ответил, а не тот чья разница правильных и неправильных ответов больше.

Comment: человек может просто тогда тыкать по ответам и когда нибудь выйдет правильный ответ, и так получать баллы, и рейтингу нет разницы получается на неправильные ответы.

Comment: не давайте менять ответ. делайте больше вариантов ответов. угадать один из двух - 50%. один из десяти - 10%. угадать будет сильно сложнее. плюс можно использовать адаптивный рейтинг - каждый последующий правильный ответ приносит больше балов.

Comment: у меня 4 варианта ответа, а про адаптивный рейтинг нужно подумать, а вариантами Google Play невозможно сделать такой рейтинг, который учитывал бы правильные и неправильные ответы?

Comment: обновил ответ. добавил идею с относительным рейтингом.